# Preg_match(): missing closing parenthesis

Tags: compilation, preg-match

A plugin is generating the following error:

> Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing closing parenthesis at offset 946 - DeferJS.php on line 78

The line of code that generates the error:

`if ( preg_match( '#(' . $exclude_defer_js . ')#i', $tag['url'] ) ) {`

Thanks for any help

Comment: What is the content of `$exclude_defer_js`?

Answer (score 1):

`$exclude_defer_js` must contain special characters.

Use [`preg_quote`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php):

```php
if ( preg_match( '#' . preg_quote($exclude_defer_js, '#') . '#i', $tag['url'] ) ) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I went to get more about the preg_quote, unfortunately the error persists on the server, on the same line, I don't understand why.

Comment: @Jader It is not related to this code. If it is some very old code, try adding the third `$match` argument to `preg_match`: `if ( preg_match( '#' . preg_quote($exclude_defer_js, '#') . '#i', $tag['url'], $match ) ) { `